# unexpected t_string, can't seem to find a answer

Tags: php, mysql

I have a weird problem with a MySQL query...

It's weird because it does not seem like it has faults in it, but it has, apparently...

This is the query:

```
$lastmessage = execute_scalar(“SELECT message FROM messages WHERE nick = 'nick' ORDER BY date LIMIT 0,1”);
```

And the error I am getting, on the same line, is this:

```
parse error: syntax error, unexpected t_string
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (Guessed the language, please always tag with the language you're using and edit your question with the correct tag if I guess wrong.) The quotes are wrong, is that a result of some weird copy/paste problem or do you really have those funky quotes in your code?

Comment: That's a result of copying and pasting, however, NKR's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `""` or `''` (which are in the ASCII charset) to note a string in PHP. In your code you are using `“` which is a Unicode character.

With `""` your code would look like this:

```
$lastmessage = execute_scalar("SELECT message FROM messages WHERE nick = 'nick' ORDER BY date LIMIT 0,1");
```

I think you copied the code from an website where the CMS automatically changed `"` to `“`.

Comment: Thanks mate, this worked like a charm, but know I am getting an even more odd problem:

`Unknown column 'nick' in where                          clause'SELECT message FROM messages WHERE nick = 'nick' ORDER BY date LIMIT 0,1`

How can this be happening if I have tons of other query in which I use the column nick?

Comment: @user1671643 I don't know your database schema so I cannot tell anything about this error. I would recommend to check the schema and analyze the other queries. Maybe there is no column `nick` in `messages` but in `users` and your have to join the tables.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem indeed, I solved it, but thanks anyway! I love this site... 

I can't give you reputation points, but you certainly deserved it. Cheers!

Comment: @user1671643 There should be a white check on the left side of my post. You can click on it to accept the answer. Normally you have to wait a few minutes (10 minutes afaik) after the answer was posted. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Ah, I see. I am a newbie here, but now I know how to accept it. Thank you!